# How to assign object independent collision detection

Tags: python, tkinter, tuples, collision-detection, collision

I'm trying to get ball objects on the canvas to collide, and move appropriately. I have some extra movement vars that are not important for my question, but I'd like to keep them the way they are. My ball:

```
class Ball(Coords):
def __init__(self,canvas,color,drawX1,drawY1,drawX2,drawY2,startX,startY,moveX,moveY):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.drawX1 = drawX1
    self.drawY1 = drawY1
    self.drawX2 = drawX2
    self.drawY2 = drawY2
    self.startX = startX
    self.startY = startY
    self.moveX = moveX
    self.moveY = moveY
    self.id = canvas.create_oval(drawX1,drawY1,drawX2,drawY2, fill=color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id,self.startX,self.startY)



def draw(self,ran1,ran2):
    self.ran1 = ran1
    self.ran2 = ran2
    ranspeed = random.randint(ran1,ran2)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)       
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
    self.canvas.move(self.id,self.moveX,self.moveY)
```

The variables in ball's init just let me change various attributes the ball has, and in draw I set the speed to a random int range because I like it that way.

I decided to use tkinters get overlapping func to get the item IDs of balls so I could make collision object indepent. My problem is that the result is a tuple which I cannot use to extract the item ID out of in order to perform some movement operation on it. My collision check code is inside of the draw function, and looks like this:

```
pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
```

inside = canvas.find_overlapping(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2],pos[3])

```
    if pos[0] <= 0:         
        self.moveX = ranspeed
    if pos[1] <= 0:
        self.moveY = ranspeed
    if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
        self.moveX = ranspeed*-1
    if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
        self.moveY = ranspeed*-1
```

Also note that the tuple also returns self.id because it's in itself, so I exclude the first tuple index:

```
idcolliders = inside[1:]
```

When I print idcolliders, I receive a stream of tuples for ballobject one - last, containing all of the id's currently within its' coords.
Is there a way to get an ID result from this tuple and put it in a function to change it (move it, specifically) while it exists, that doesn't throw errors while it doesn't?

Comment: While I'm sure you can do this with tkinter, may I suggest that you use pygame instead? I think you may have a much easier time (in the long run at least) even though you may need to learn a brand new module. Pygame has inbuilt classes and functions to handle collision detection and will probably end up being much faster than doing it with the tkinter canvas. Good luck

Comment: Yes, learning a new module would be time-consuming, but more importantly, I don't know if pygame will do what I want for this program. I still need to be able to synthesize the "balls" numerically, something that is very hard to do when using .png or .bmp.  Is there a way to interface pygame with tkinters canvas?

Comment: I doubt there is a to interface them together but your algorithms can probably easily be adapted to suit pygame. Graphics need to be imported from image files, you can draw things in pygame using pygames `draw` methods. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html

Comment: Thanks, yes it works very well indeed, but not without problems of its own. :D

Comment: Ah, I'm glad I was able to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tkinter's [bbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) to get the 4 tuples, x1,y1,x2,y2 for your item canvas.bbox(item) and then use that in a math calculation to check if other items or your item is inside another items tuples.